# Content/information organization on the intranet home pages

Tags: intranet, information-architecture

Which are the most useful information/content blocks on an intranet  home page? What are those functionalities requested by end users? - I am interested on past experiences...

Answer (score 1):

It really all depends on the culture and size of the organization. However some past examples would include something like tip of the day. It can be general on how to use sharepoint, or something specific to the industry. Other items could be a stock ticker, recent management blog posts, rss feeds that are industry specific, the company in the news, links to common resources.

Comment: yes, I agree with you(regarding the culture, even the business)...I just wanted to have some feedbacks on commonly asked functionalities/information...thanks for your answer!